# vue custom component library unable to use global plugin (primevue)

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I have a custom Component library (with components based on Primevue).

One of the components in that library use the DialogService from Primevue.
In the devserver the plugin is installed like this: app.use(DialogService).

But when I use this library in my real app, (where I also installed the DialogService Plugin the same way),

the dialog does not open and devtools say that no PrimeVue Dialog is provided!

What can i do that my lib will use the plugin?

when using my custom library, the library should be able to use the global plugin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.